# Sending Message from NIO Server

Tags: java, sockets, nio

The code below successfully creates a server and accepts an incoming client.

```
package socket;

import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class NonBlockingServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        // Create a new Thread
        Server s = new Server();
        new Thread(s).start();

        // Give 10 seconds for client to connect
        Thread.sleep(10000);

// This Doesn't work?

        s.Write("Hello, Client!");

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}

//A class which implements Runnable Interface
class Server implements Runnable  {

    SocketChannel AcceptedClient;
    ServerSocketChannel serverChannel;
    Selector selector;

    void Write(String s) throws IOException {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(s.length());
        buffer.put(s.getBytes());

        int numWrite = -1;
        numWrite = AcceptedClient.write(buffer);

        while (buffer.hasRemaining())
        {
            numWrite += AcceptedClient.write(buffer);
        }

        System.out.println(numWrite);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        int port = 4041;

        System.out.println("Listening for connections on port " + port);

        try {
            // Bind the port
            serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            ServerSocket ss = serverChannel.socket();
            InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(port);
            ss.bind(address);

            // Non-blocking Server
            serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);

            // Register with Selector
            selector = Selector.open();
            serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        while (true) {

            try {

                // Blocks until a 'socket' is ready registered with selector is ready.
                selector.select();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }

            Set<SelectionKey> readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = readyKeys.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                SelectionKey key = iterator.next();
                iterator.remove();

                try {

                    if (key.isAcceptable()) {

                        ServerSocketChannel server = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
                        SocketChannel client = server.accept();
                        System.out.println("Accepted connection from " + client);
                        client.configureBlocking(false);

                        // Client accepted by server can read.
                        SelectionKey key2 = client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

                        AcceptedClient = (SocketChannel) key2.channel();

                    }

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    key.cancel();
                    try {
                        key.channel().close();
                    } catch (IOException cex) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to send a message to client after it has been connected to server, it doesn't work i.e. the message is not received by client.

What's the correct way to send a message from server to a specific client?

I have looked over the Internet and didn't find any examples in which server sends a message to client.

Comment: You didn't look very hard. The Internet is full of NIO send and receive examples. The Java Tutorial, for a start, not to mention this site. I've answered hundreds of questions on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `flip()` the buffer before the `write()`, and if you're going to keep it you need to `compact()` it afterwards.

NB Closing the channel cancels the key.

Comment: It worked after flipping. Thank you, EJP! I want to know If I want the server to broadcast the message to all connected clients, then would i use OP_WRITE?

Comment: The more important question I have now is about closing the ServerSocketChannel. It has a threads, connected clients to server, selector, and server itself. Could you help me with order to start closing stuff please?

Comment: Err, `ServerSocketChannel.close()`, `SocketChannel.close()`, and `Selector.close()`? If you have new questions, ask them as new questions. This is not a forum.